# plot a heatmap with a third dimension

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I would like to plot a heatmap like this

[image]

I know how to do a normal heatmap in R but am unsure how the 3D component can be introduced. I thought about just using a 3d bar chart but then I am not sure how to conditionally set the bar colour. Can somebody recommend a tool to do something like this?
Another example would be [here](http://learnr.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/chapter06-06_15_l.png)

but there it is not coloured according to the heatmap colours.

This might go also by the name of 3D histogram. Is there a way to produce such a figure in R (where the hight of the boxes is given by 1 variable and the colour formatting indicated by another ?) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756925/how-to-plot-heatmap-colors-in-3d-in-matplotlib)

My problem with JTT solution is that I would need to be able to colour the 3D Bars independently of the VA Deaths variable. I have a 2D heatmap (which do already set the colours for each 3D bar). The height of the bar is then set by another variable. This means the colour is not related to the height.

Comment: do you _really_ want that? It's a terrible plot, you're hiding some data behind the taller bars, and it's almost impossible to compare the heights in this perspective.

Comment: although that is a valid point I do have to present it in that way...or say I was told to do it in that way by a superior, what would be equal alternatives? Or is there a way to do this like I outlined?

Comment: I would make two side-by-side colour maps in 2D. Or, depending on the data, superpose some points on the tiles of a 2D colour map to map the last variable. "Throwing in extra dimensions is often counterproductive" (Cleveland).

Comment: although I agree with your point I am wondering whether there is a way to do that in R. In my data set most of the bars will be quite low except for a couple of bars in the middle which will be very high. Hence I thought it wouldn't be too bad

Comment: @baptiste: it is absolutely NOT a terrible plot because the idea is not to obtain accurate numerical comparisons but to get an idea of the topology of a multidimensional data set. The workflow for such data sets inevitably involves first getting an idea of the interesting bits, before "zooming in" with more accurate plots by slicing and projecting back into 2d, and it is only at that later stage that we want visual accuracy. First we need to figure out what's going on at a high "unaccurate" level. If we don't perform this crucial first step, we'll be looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne I have yet to see a 3D barplot more useful than the corresponding 2D colour map. Here's a [comparison of those two approaches](http://imgur.com/8OdR6bz) (I made the version on the right) -- there's just nothing gained from using a false 3D perspective: in the same space I was able to fit way more legible information, and nothing is hidden / distorted.

Comment: @baptiste yes ultimately we are working on a 2d medium (the screen) so the 3d plot is a projection onto 2d and is unable, mathematically, to convey more information than the colour map. *However*, the human brain is much more sensitive to height information than colour information, and so my experience is that rotatable 3-d barplot is a useful tool as it has a more intuitive mapping to the magnitudes. This is especially true when the task at hand is to convey information to non-scientists, a frequent requirement in industry and business. Colour is a more distant abstraction than size.

Comment: @baptiste ..... you will agree, for example, that when we are talking about a 2d data set, we *never* use a colour mapping instead of a distance mapping. We always use a 2d distance chart. This proves that distance is much better when it is possible. I maintain therefore that your characterization of the OP's chart as "terrible" is unfair.

Comment: i agree with @ThomasBrowne on a 3d heatmap being more brian-friendly than the 2d equivalent. if data has a clear shape, its easier for us to comprehend.

Answer (score 5):

3D barchart might be a way to go. There's `panel.3dbars()` in the package latticeExtra that you might want to test. See the function's help page for more examples, but here's one example modified from one of the examples on the help page:

```
library(latticeExtra)
# A function generating colors
cols<-function(n) {
   colorRampPalette(c("#FFC0CB", "#CC0000"))(20)                                 # 20 distinct colors
}
# The plot
cloud(VADeaths, panel.3d.cloud = panel.3dbars, col="white",                      # white borders for bars
  xbase = 1, ybase = 1, zlim = c(0, max(VADeaths)),                              # No space around the bars
  scales = list(arrows = FALSE, just = "right"), xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,
  col.facet = level.colors(VADeaths, at = do.breaks(range(VADeaths), 20),        
                           col.regions = cols,                                   # color ramp for filling the bars
                           colors = TRUE),
  colorkey = list(col = cols, at = do.breaks(range(VADeaths), 20)),
  screen = list(z = 65, x = -65))                                                # Adjust tilting
```

The resulting is similar to:

[image]

Note that the data to be plotted needs to be turned into a matrix for this to work. If you have measurement from X*Y grid, where Z is the intensity of the measurement, this should be rather straightforward to pull off. The functions here (e.g., `level.colors()`) automatically decides the color according to the data range, but you can also generate the colors yourself, before plotting.

Comment: hey...that looks nice but I dont really see a way how to incorporate the heatmap colour coding? In your example the colour of the 3D Bars depends on the age axis. How could I just let the colour of a specific 3D bar be determined by a vector of colours or something like this?

Comment: The colors in this example are dependent on the z variable (death rates) that is dependent on age. The higher the death rate, the darker the red color. You can define the colors by hand, if you must, but in general it works best to let R decide the colors for the bars. A notable exception is the case where z takes only few distinct values. See the second example in `?panel.3dbars`. It uses terrain.colors for coloring the bars. If you want the "heatmap colors" you might want to substitute that by heat.colors.

Comment: my problem is that I would need to be able to colour the 3D Bars independently of the third variable. I have a 2D heatmap (which do already set the colours for each 3D bar). The height of the bar is then set by another variable. This means the colour is not related to the height.

Comment: If you need to set the colors by hand, then you can give argument `col.facet` just a simple vector of colors. Figuring the right order of the colors in the vector is sometimes a bit painful (or then its just me), but in this particular example substituting the existing argument with `col.facet = rep(1:4, each=5)` would color each column of the data with a separate color.

Comment: By the way, there needs to be exactly one color per bar in the plot. If there are less colors than bars, the colors will get reused , which creates "nice" anomalies in the plot.

Comment: that's great...how can i determine which colours to add? There is no link to colrefpalette in the line you mention. This is the reason I was wondering how you specify each colour if you use col.facet=rep(1:4, each=5). Is it also possible to colour bars in different rows with the same colour ?

Comment: Figuring the coloring takes some thinking, because they are specified in relation to the data, not the plot, which might be rotated like here. Let's assign different colors to different bars. Using `colorRampPalette(c("white", "black"))(20)`would give colors from white to black to the bars. The first bar (youngest rural male) is colored white, and light greys are used for the rest of that column. Then the second column is colored with the next five colors, and so forth. You said earlier that you have the colors for the 2D heatmap, so you can use them, you just need to figure the right order.

Comment: So the `colorRampPalette...` in the previous comment goes to the `col.facet` argument. You can also put it for the col argument, if you want to color the borders of the bars with same colors.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution using `persp` to generate a 3d perspective and then drawing rectangles to generate bars. A lot of lines, but pretty flexible. You need to provide a data matrix (`data`) and a color matrix ( `colmat`).

```
# generate data, random + linear trend in x + linear trend in y
data = matrix(data = runif(n = 100, min = 0, max = 1), nrow=10, ncol = 10, dimnames=list(paste0('x',1:10),paste0('y',1:10)))
data = sweep(x = data, MARGIN = 1, 10:1, FUN = '+')
data = sweep(x = data, MARGIN = 2, 1:10, FUN = '+')

# generate 'empty' persp plot
pmat = persp(x=c(0,10), y=c(0,10), z=matrix(c(0,.1,0,.1), nrow=2), 
             xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), zlim=c(0,20), 
             xlab='x', ylab='y', zlab='z', 
             theta=60, phi=20, d=2, box=F) 

# define color ramp
my_cols = heat.colors(10)

# generate color matrix (values between 1 and 10, corresponding to 10 values my_cols
colmat = matrix(data = 1, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
colmat[1,1:10] <- 5
colmat[5,2:4] <- 8
colmat[6,8] <- 3

# draw each bar: from left to right ...
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){

  # ... and back to front 
  for (j in ncol(data):1){

    xy = which(data == data[i,j], arr.ind=TRUE)

    # side facing y
    x = rep(xy[1],4)
    y = c(xy[2]-1,xy[2],xy[2],xy[2]-1)
    z = c(0,0,data[i,j],data[i,j])
    polygon(trans3d(x, y, z, pmat), col=my_cols[colmat[i,j]], border=1)

    #  side facing x
    x = c(xy[1]-1,xy[1],xy[1],xy[1]-1)
    y = rep(xy[2]-1,4)
    z = c(0,0,data[i,j],data[i,j])
    polygon(trans3d(x, y, z, pmat), col=my_cols[colmat[i,j]], border=1)

    # top side
    x = c(xy[1]-1,xy[1],xy[1],xy[1]-1)
    y = c(xy[2]-1,xy[2]-1,xy[2],xy[2])
    z = rep(data[i,j],4)
    polygon(trans3d(x, y, z, pmat), col=my_cols[colmat[i,j]], border=1)

  }
}

# define axis ranges etc
x.axis <- 1:ncol(data) - 0.5
min.x <- 0
max.x <- 10
y.axis <- 1:nrow(data) - 0.5 
min.y <- 0
max.y <- 10
z.axis <- seq(0, 10, by=10)
min.z <- 0
max.z <- 10

# add some distance between tick labels and the axis
xoffset = 1
yoffset = 0.5
zoffset = 0.5
ticklength = 0.2

# x axis ticks
tick.start <- trans3d(x.axis, min.y, min.z, pmat)
tick.end <- trans3d(x.axis, (min.y - ticklength), min.z, pmat)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)

# y axis ticks
tick.start <- trans3d(max.x, y.axis, min.z, pmat)
tick.end <- trans3d(max.x + ticklength, y.axis, min.z, pmat)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)

# z axis ticks
tick.start <- trans3d(min.x, min.y, z.axis, pmat)
tick.end <- trans3d(min.x, (min.y - ticklength), z.axis, pmat)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)

# x labels
labels <- rownames(data)
label.pos <- trans3d(x.axis, (min.y - xoffset), min.z, pmat)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels=labels, adj=c(0, NA), srt=0, cex=0.6)

# y labels
labels <- colnames(data)
label.pos <- trans3d((max.x + yoffset), y.axis, min.z, pmat)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels=labels, adj=c(0, NA), srt=0, cex=0.6)

# z labels
labels <- as.character(z.axis)
label.pos <- trans3d(min.x, (min.y - zoffset), z.axis, pmat)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels=labels, adj=c(1, NA), srt=0, cex=0.6)
```

[image]

Comment: is it somehow possible to label the axes with the row and column names of the data matrix (x an y ) and the z with something like a scale from 0 to 1?

Comment: what do you mean with offsets, when I replicate your code I have the labels with the ticks on the lin of the box in which the box plot is drawn as well as additional lines parallel to the x and y and z of the box http://www.pic-upload.de/view-24082805/Rplot05.png.html
 . Is there a way to remove the large box (as in the example you show above). I just re-entered your code
]

Comment: in the x .is there a way for the x labels to be not angeled but just to be straight away from the x ? So that they do not overlap with each other

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, had to do edits in a hurry. Now axis labels should be fine and box should  be gone. Angles can be changed by adjusting the `srt` argument (String RoTation, I guess). I updated the values so they're all horizontal now.  You can change them to any value between 0 and 360 to see what's best.