# Plot 3D orography of a grid

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to replicate something like the following plot using R, possibly using ggplot (though I doubt it is possible as, AFAIK, it has no 3D capabilities). The data I have is usually a raster file from the raster package, but I can transform it in the most suitable format.

[image]

The plot is taken from:
"Climate Change 2013: The Physical Science Basis. Contribution of Working Group I to the Fifth Assessment Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change", figure 1.14. I have no idea which software has produced that plot.

I guess the only is to use lattice::cloud (wireframe) or something like this? I can't seem to find any way to force wireframe to have a ind of barplot instead of a surface plot; additionally, the coloring based on the height over the sea, where the grid is kept level, is probably impossible..

Comment: it will be a significant amount of work, but the `rgl` package could certainly be made to do this.  Take a look at `demo("hist3d",package="rgl")`

Comment: Agreed to @BenBolker. Maybe here is a starting point: http://spatial.ly/2013/05/3d-mapping-r/.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that rasterVis has a wrapper around rgl that allows to easily plot 3D surfaces. I'm trying to adapt it to my needs.

Comment: Perhaps you can build on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25042436/2516066) answer. It's flexible and allows you to use a saparate colormap.

Comment: @koekenbakker Thanks. I have found a possible solution (see my own answer below), but it can be slow for very large plots (and i do mean large). I'll try to find some time to take a look at those two answers too.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I found a solution (thanks to Ben Bolker), see my answer below.

Comment: Why do you want to produce a graphic like this? The colour and height seem to be encoding the same data, so one is redundant, and the 3d nature means some squares are obscured. Just do a flat coloured raster plot and eschew the eye candy for a moment.

Comment: @Spacedman I also did a flat raster plot. I have datasets at various resolution, the difference is much more easy to grasp when viewed directly comparing 3D plots. Just check "Climate Change 2013: The Physical Science Basis. Contribution of Working Group I to the Fifth Assessment Report of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change", figure 1.14 and you'll see what I mean. Also, I want to do 3D rotable graphics so that one can zoom and see the differences in the chosen area. In the end, however, it's mostly to learn to do something new that could be useful in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some time to look at this. In the end I took the following approach (linked R code):

http://pastebin.com/dA2nNNS0

Thanks to those in the comments who pointed me in the right direction.

I still have problems saving the file but that's material for another Question.

Code from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dA2nNNS0):

```
library(raster) 
library(rgl)

r <- raster("topo12.nc", varname="topo") #Read file
cols <- terrain.colors(3100) #Define colors

binplot.3d <- function(x,y,z,alpha=1,topcol="#ff0000",sidecol="#aaaaaa"){ #Binplotting function
  save <- par3d(skipRedraw=TRUE)
  on.exit(par3d(save))

  x1<-c(rep(c(x[1],x[2],x[2],x[1]),3),rep(x[1],4),rep(x[2],4))
  z1<-c(rep(0,4),rep(c(0,0,z,z),4))
  y1<-c(y[1],y[1],y[2],y[2],rep(y[1],4),rep(y[2],4),rep(c(y[1],y[2],y[2],y[1]),2))
  x2<-c(rep(c(x[1],x[1],x[2],x[2]),2),rep(c(x[1],x[2],rep(x[1],3),rep(x[2],3)),2))
  z2<-c(rep(c(0,z),4),rep(0,8),rep(z,8) )
  y2<-c(rep(y[1],4),rep(y[2],4),rep(c(rep(y[1],3),rep(y[2],3),y[1],y[2]),2) )
  rgl.quads(x1,z1,y1,col=rep(sidecol,each=4),alpha=alpha)
  rgl.quads(c(x[1],x[2],x[2],x[1]),rep(z,4),c(y[1],y[1],y[2],y[2]),
              col=rep(topcol,each=4),alpha=1) 
  rgl.lines(x2,z2,y2,col="#000000")
}

cat("Row ( of", dim(r)[1],"):")
for (row in 1:dim(r)[1]) { #Plotting loop
    for (col in 1:dim(r)[2]) {
    if (round(r[row, col]) < 1) {
    binplot.3d(c(col-1,col), c(row-1,row), r[row, col]/500, alpha=1, topcol="cadetblue3")
    } else {
    binplot.3d(c(col-1,col), c(row-1,row), r[row, col]/500, alpha=1, topcol=cols[round(r[row, col])])
#   cat(round(r[row, col]), "\t")
    }
    }
    cat(row, "")
}
```